# How to create a django form with a select list initialized from a dynamic query?

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

I'm trying to build a form where a select list can be initialized from a tuple parameter I pass in on creation of the form object.

I tried doing the following, which worked for CREATING the form.  But when I try to submit the form, I get an is_valid() = false error.  In the example below the myrooms variable is the data I'd like to dynamically load upon initialization of the form.  Any help here?

```
class SessionInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):

     def __init__(self, myrooms = None, *args, **kwargs):
         super(SessionInfoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         if myrooms != None:
             self.fields['room'].choices = myrooms

     class Meta:
         model = SessionInfo
         fields = ["title", "room", "viewer_limit", "starttime", "endtime", "billing_type", "billing_value"]
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: it's customary/idiomatic to write `if myrooms *is not* None` (rather than `!=`)

Comment: Can you also the view code where you initialize the form? Make sure you always pass the same values for `myroom`, also when the form is initialized after the post request!

Answer (score 1):

Your are probably forgetting to pass the same list to `myrooms` when validating the results.

You have to pass it *both* for the rendering and the validating.

Answer (score 0):

just change `self.fields['room'].choices = myrooms` to `self.fields['room'].widget.choices = myrooms` , i have already edited that into your question